# Is it possible to make an object in VB change colour depending on the score received from a quiz?

Tags: vb.net, colors

Is it possible to make an object in VB change colour depending on the score received from a quiz?

E.g. A person scored above 75% so therefore would turn green

Comment: what kind of "object in VB" are we talking about (the one that will change color)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  For example

```
If Score > x Then Control.BackColor = Color.Green
```